# 32 bit drivers for egistec ES603 windows 10/8

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint, biometrics

I recently purchased a EgisTec ES603 for use with the new windows hello feature and biometric security in windows 10. The 64 bit drivers are easily found however i have a 32 bit tablet and would greatly appreciate if anyone knew where to locate the drivers and directed me there. Thanks

Comment: There was no driver disc that came with it? Questions regarding finding a product or service are off-topic for Super User. A quick Google revealed this: http://www.driverscape.com/download/egistec-es603 It looks like it will detect your version of Windows. Does it find a 32-bit driver for you?

Comment: the cd that was supplied with it contained old drivers and the bioexcess program which never functioned properly on my device. upon installing the 64 bit drivers on my other PC windows then updated the drivers and it worked seamlessly. The only difference between the two is the 64 bit and 32 bit versions of windows 10. I am unaware as to if there is a 32 bit alternative to "http://goo.gl/QNGxah" Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand, was your problem solved? Also the link did not work. Did you resolve the issue? If so, you could answer your own question in case any others have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The 32-Bit and 64-Bit drivers are contained in the same file.  See here for more details: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-b-series-laptops/lenovo-b470e-notebook/20172/downloads/ds019457